# How to execute xcopy in parallel inside a batch file?

Tags: batch-file, cmd, multiprocessing

I have multiple xcopy statements in a batch file. I need to execute them in parallel so that the copying gets over soon. How do I achieve that? It cannot run in separate windows because I have certain parameters in xcopy statements which will be replaced by values that is set in another batch file. Please help.

Comment: It can be executed in separate window since the parameters set in another batch file is carried over to the new window.

Comment: You can use the START command to launch a parallel process, but it is likely going to slow things down if anything. The drive head can only do one thing at a time. So there is no advantage to having multiple processes, and there is overhead in managing resources shared by multiple processes.

Answer (score 1):

You can't. Rethink your approach. And why do you think moving the heads back and forth would be quicker.

Comment: because they might be on different drives?

Comment: @triggeradeadcat, copying one after the other will obviously take more time when compared to executing it in parallel

Comment: @Mehrdad, copying is in same drive

Comment: @naveenbharadwaj Copying one after the other will obviously take *less* time overall. The disk drive can do one thing at a time. If you make it alternate between tasks, you add the overhead (moving the read head) of swapping between those tasks. Of course, it could be that the files are small and happen to be on the same track and get cached in some fortunate way, but that is not likely to be the case in general.

Comment: @AndrewMorton, lets say i have 4 folders A,B,C,D. I'm copying A contents to B and C contents to D. There are quite a number of files in A and C. Copying one after the other takes 10 minutes (5 minutes for each), lets say. Parallelizing should take 5-6 minutes and both should get completed.

Comment: @naveenbharadwaj Why do you think it will be faster? The disk drive cannot do things in parallel. It is the bottleneck in the copying process, and you are suggesting that making it do more work will make it go faster.

Comment: @AndrewMorton - I wonder if there might be some benefit on a solid state drive? I suppose there may still be a bottleneck at the controller. Just curious.

Comment: @dbenham You could give [robocopy](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc733145.aspx) a test - it includes a multi-thread option. I have no idea why it would be faster than a single thread, unless there is noticeable processing overhead due to ~something~.